# Create a public link to download a file from my webserver

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a qrcode file and uploading it to my web server via ASP.NET MVC. My web server is hosting server online to a folder where my web files are located. When i click the link directly the response is page can't be found. I want the user i send the link to be able to download file. New to this. Anyone who can show how to make the file downloadable.

I uploaded the file correctly but when I click on the link to the file on the server I get the result page cannot be found instead of the file being downloaded.

Comment: Please upload some code

Comment: Please provide some code snippets, I am assuming that you have a controller which returns file, if yes check your router path, for example qrfile/download is match with your link provided.